Using a function's argument to produce the type of another function's argument
Since C++20 abbreviated function templates are available for use with placeholder types in parameter list. And one can declare abbreviated function template g with two arguments of same reference type using decltype:
int g( auto && p, decltype(p) );

This question is about more complex type relations between function template arguments, in particular, can lambda expressions be used for type transformations.
In the example program as follows function template f having two arguments declares the type of the second argument by using decltype with lambda expression inside referring to the first function's argument p (here for illustration purposes it just removes the reference from the type same as std::remove_reference_t but without including <type_traits>):
int f( auto && p, 
    decltype([p](){return p;}()) ) //#1
    { return 0; }

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    return f( i, 0 );
}

Unfortunately, GCC rejects it with the error:

error: use of parameter outside function body before ';' token

MSVC:

error C3536: 'p': cannot be used before it is initialized

Clang's error is less clear:

error: variable 'p' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oeWMb6ozo
And if one uses an initializer for lambda capture:
int f( auto && p, 
    decltype([p=p](){return p;}()) ) //#2
    { return 0; }

the behavior of compilers does change.
MSVC:

error C2853: 'p': a non-static data member cannot have a type that contains 'auto'

Clang simply crashes.
But GCC accepts program #2 just fine. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ebco5cYsh
Is program #2 really well-formed and #1 not? What are the limitations on using function template arguments for defining types of other arguments?

You are showing an invalid code. Please explain what you expect to achieve? Which type should be at the second parameter?

Why are you using decltype on a non-existant lambda in the first place? Why not just use it on p directly, and then pass the result to std::remove_reference_t? int f( auto && p, std::remove_reference_t<decltype(p)>)

Yes, in the example I would like to get the same result to std::remove_reference_t. Can one use the combination of decltype + lambda for that, or is it prohibited by the standard?

Weirdest code I ever saw, who cares?

@Fedor there is no actual lambda in the example you have shown. It makes no sense. Please [edit] your question to provide a better example that is more representative of real code you are struggling with. It probably would be better to simply get rid of auto in this case since you want to use the same type in 2 places, eg: template <typename T> int f( T&&, T )

"Clang simply crashes." -- It could be you've concocted a weird enough case that the compilers did not test it. In any event, "GCC accepts program #2 just fine" is not enough evidence to support the "really" in "Is program #2 really well-formed". There could be a compiler bug or maybe this falls under "no diagnostic required".

Everyone seems confused here. This is a language lawyer question. Is the code well-formed or not?
